# sax parser exception while generating allure results

Tags: rest, testing, saxparser, allure

I am using Allure framework to generate test reports.
Used as a maven dependency in test framework.

While running tests in jenkins, Allure created reports as expected, however there are few exceptions in the console for xml files generated by allure.
Allure is creating xml files from test information, however it generates xml file from rest API response which is in html/JSON format, and since it is not a valid xml file, Sax Parser exception is thrown.

I am unable to understand how to resolve these exceptions.

Below is snippet of exception
[Fatal Error] da669b14-4d30-4260-8815-eab1f720661b-attachment.xml:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Could not parse file /home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_trunk-H4U6TKVVIR44VYBZR7Q53HWUDRP5C3JJEEVZOEYQTCQK53LROIJA/.ci-reports/allure-results/da669b14-4d30-4260-8815-eab1f720661b-attachment.xml: {}
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/jenkins/workspace/amp-adengine_trunk-H4U6TKVVIR44VYBZR7Q53HWUDRP5C3JJEEVZOEYQTCQK53LROIJA/.ci-reports/allure-results/da669b14-4d30-4260-8815-eab1f720661b-attachment.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)
    at io.qameta.allure.junitxml.JunitXmlPlugin.parseRootElement(JunitXmlPlugin.java:97)
    at io.qameta.allure.junitxml.JunitXmlPlugin.lambda$readResults$0(JunitXmlPlugin.java:87)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at io.qameta.allure.junitxml.JunitXmlPlugin.readResults(JunitXmlPlugin.java:87)
    at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.lambda$readResults$0(ReportGenerator.java:32)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.readResults(ReportGenerator.java:32)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:54)
    at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:43)
    at io.qameta.allure.Commands.generate(Commands.java:89)
    at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:129)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:72)

Response from API will always be HTML/JSON and will not be xml response ever.
Can someone guide me to resolve these exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really depends on how you use Allure to save attachments. In general, it is possible to specify MIME type and file extension when saving attachment

```
@Attachment(value = "API response", type = "application/json", fileExtension = ".json")
public String requestAPI() {
    ...
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, helped me to find correct solution.